# how to convert programatically powerpoint to xml and back

Tags: java, xml, powerpoint

I need to convert powerpoint file to a text based file such as xml o html programatically and do some proccesses in it and again convert the textbased file top powerpoint. I prefer to do it with java.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) and specifically [POI-HSLF](http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/index.html)

You need to read the ppt and extract the contents and form your xml doc. Post manipulation you need to create back the ppt.